# Problem with tokenization of text, it does not work

Tags: r, tidytext

I have the following text in a file called `prueba.txt`:

> "Gobernando líderes: una reflexión sobre el fútbol como sistema de juego complejo"
> "La innovación y el aprendizaje en las organizaciones son actividades clave en la empresa actual. A menos que se tenga tendencia a la megalomanía, se reconocerá que las transformaciones y los cambios se deben a la interacción de muchas personas, algunas de ellas líderes. Por tanto, en el ámbito de la innovación, una capacidad directiva clave es la de gobernar líderes. Para explorar este tema, resulta interesante aproximarse al mundo del fútbol como un sistema de juego complejo, en el que conviven diversos líderes en un mismo campo y con el que se pueden explorar diversas dimensiones: la ideológica, la dinámica organizativa, el aprendizaje colectivo y el papel de la improvisación. Todo ello extrapolable como forma de pensamiento al mundo de la empresa."
> "El ser humano tiene como elemento distintivo su alta energía psíquica y su creatividad, lo que le permite ser multidisciplinar, abierto al entorno y comunicativo. Y juega porque está en su naturaleza. Por encima de todo, es un ser autónomo, no una máquina de estímulo-respuesta o una “bête machine”, por utilizar la terminología de Descartes, porque concebirlo como tal es demasiado reduccionista para comprender la voluntad de jugar, crear y aprender."

I am running the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

library(tidytext)

text<-read.table("prueba.txt")

text_df <- tibble(line = 1:3, Text = text)

ncol(text_df)

text_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, Text)
```

And obtain the following output:

> Error in is_corpus_df(corpus) : ncol(corpus) >= 2 is not TRUE

But I've verified and the text that I am using has 2 columns, so it should work. Can you please help me figure out if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug in the library?

Comment: Try ``text[,1] %>% tibble(txt = .) %>% unnest_tokens(word, txt)``

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried what you suggested and this is the output I get:
Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.

Comment: What is the ``dim(text)``? You need to pass a character vector to tibble, if you want to use tibble like in the example. Can you try ``text<-readLines("prueba.txt")``, and check if  ``text %>% tibble(txt = .) %>% unnest_tokens(word, txt)`` works?

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks! I really appreciate it.